# non-uniform distribution in a range

Tags: python, range, sample, logarithm, datapoint

I would like to generate a non-uniform data set in a range which has more data points at the end-tale. Suppose the range is [a-b], a,b>0, and I want to find a way in python to generate a non-uniform data with more data points near the upper bound. Something like reverse of log distribution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already a distribution in mind you can use [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html).

```python
from scipy import stats


a = 2 # just an example min-range value
b = 10 # just an example max-range value
data = stats.beta(2,8)*(b-a) + a # you can alter the shape of the distribution by playing with parameters
```

[Here](https://www.vosesoftware.com/riskwiki/Betadistribution.php) you can find more about beta distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but Beta distribution does not lie in the range [0,1].

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution?wprov=sfla1